# find unique rows using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return all the rows from a table which are unique. I.e. if a certain field in two rows contain the same name, that name shouldn't be shown.

Comment: Please, provide some sample data and the output you expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you want only the uniques names (and not an unique row for every names like you could have with `DISTINCT`), you have to use a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` (instead of a `WHERE`, because your parameter is the result of a function, not a variable) :

```
SELECT name FROM myTable GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) = 1
```

Comment: Why not DISTINCT - is it slower?

Comment: Because "distinct" will return you a unique row for every names, not only the uniques names.

Comment: OK, understood. I have not paid attention on this detail.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table

Answer (score 0):

If you want the complete *rows*, then use `row_number()` or `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (name) t.*
from table t
order by name;
```